# How do I leave the Psychameron?

Tags: darksiders-2

I've beaten the third Dead Lord but can't get out of the area that he is located in.  I can see the door but there are retractable spikes in my way.

How can I get back to the King of the Dead?

Comment: There is no direct exit from the Psychameron, other than Fast Travel.  As far as I can recall, the game directs you to use Fast Travel after you defeat the boss at the end of the dungeon.  The same holds for the Ivory Citadel later in the game.

Answer (score 4):

Some areas in the game require that you leave them via **Fast Travel**. Open your map, make sure the quest list isn't open and highlight a location of the map you'd like to travel to, if it's an area you can fast travel to (every "gate" on the map allows that as well as some merchants) you'll be able to fast travel to that location.

Fast Travel isn't available at all times though, for example, when you need to trigger a cutscene before leaving a location.